# Weird graphical glitch in Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-11, windows-server-2022

I'm running Windows 11 on a development machine and I often use RDP (remote desktop connection) to connect to remote server to do work.

However, something weird happened yesterday: all of a sudden one of the machines I regularly connect to (a Windows Server 2022 Datacenter machine) has started to show me weird graphical glitches, like you see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Basically there are all these weird black squares with a white line on the bottom that seem to randomly appear on top every application. They only cover part of the app, and they move around as you resize/scroll the window, but never disappear.

Has anyone ever seen something like this? Any solutions I could try? Some additional notes:

- I'm not sure, but I suspect the problem could be on my PC rather than on the server. I say this because I asked a colleague to try to connect to the same server and he doesn't experience these glitches
- I've already rebooted both my PC and the server
- The glitches doesn't seem to affect the desktop or taskbar/start menu, only the apps' windows, as you can see in the screen.

Comment: @John: production

Answer (score 2):

Well, I've found a "solution" (workaround I guess?). If you disable this option:

[image]

it fixes the problem. Still don't know why it was working before without disabling the option though...

Comment: +1 The question and answer, inexplicable as it might be, likely could help others.